# what is the main task or role of interfaces in oop

Tags: web-services, oop, interface

I have two questions:

1. Please tell me what is the main task or role of interfaces in oop.
2. Explain the role of interfaces in web services.(plz show me an
   example in c#).

Comment: I have read some topics but i did not understand, exactly what is the main idea of interfaces.

Comment: Please look at this example :                if(myObject is Boat)
    ((Boat)myObject).Drive()
else
    if (myObject is Car)
        ((Car)myObject).Drive()


It would be much much simpler to write:
((IDrivable)myObject).Drive()

Comment: This example shows when we have same behavior (driving) in some classes, we need to use interfaces.but why we say, interfaces must be used when we have a task(behavior) it's not related to every sub classes in inheritance so that behavior should be declare as interface.which solution is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very hard to tell the **main** task or role of `interface` because `interface` itself is a tool and different developers may use it differently.

And there is an interesting use of `interface` which is to achieve `polymorphism` like in Inversion of Control, Factory Design Pattern, Strategy Design Pattern ... (to name some).

Interfaces don't care about HOW, they care about WHAT. What methods/behaviors must be present in the classes that implement them. And these classes will provide the HOW.

So basically,

```
public IDrivable vehicle { get; set; }
```

and later on you can ...

```
vehicle = new Car(); // Car implements IDrivable
vehicle.Drive();
```

or ...

```
vehicle = new Boat(); // Boat implements IDrivable
vehicle.Drive();
```

Both Boat & Car have Drive() method because they were forced to implement it by IDrivable. But HOW they implement it is different from each other. Or to tell the short: `vehicle.Drive()` will behave differently, depend on the actual class you pass to it. That is polymorphism.

You can take a look at those design patterns here:

http://www.dofactory.com/net/strategy-design-pattern

http://www.dofactory.com/net/factory-method-design-pattern

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615139/An-Absolute-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Dependency-Inver

Comment: Thanks Loop for you'r help and editing. it was very usefull for me

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces are Rules.
Rules set by top management to implement by everyone in the organization to achieve a common purpose and to achieve the targets on time and within the budget.

Interfaces are rules of top most management while abstract rules are set by directors and lower level management. Experts use interface to set SOPs. Why top management does this because these are difficult to understand. All policies and plans set the rules. Child classes mean middle and lower level management. How to proceed is the function of department heads because they have relevant resources to use.